# Are fitted.values available in pglm?

Tags: r, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, count-data, poisson-regression

I am using the pglm function in R to fit a Poisson fixed-effects model. According to the documentation, the pglm object should have fitted.values. However, fitted.values(model-name) returns "NULL".

When I run AIC(model-name) the AIC is followed by "attr(,"fitted.values")" and a long list of number (see example below).

Are these fitted values? If so, is there a way to obtain them directly? Can I also get fitted-values based on a synthetic dataset (i.e. predict())?

```
install.packages("pglm")
library(pglm)

data("PatentsRDUS", package="pglm")


     model-name <- pglm(patents ~   log(rd)  + as.numeric(year)+ I(log(capital72)*as.numeric(year)) , PatentsRDUS,
     family = poisson(link=log), model = "within", index = c("cusip", "year"))

     fitted.values(model-name)
     AIC(model-name)
```

[image: R Output]